# Update specific component instance in React.js based on an ID

Tags: reactjs

In a react.js application, I’m wondering what the best practices are to give each component an ID that can be used to update only that component’s information as needed.

For example, if we have a component that displays sales information and we create and display 20 of them because we have 20 products, then at an interval we retrieve JSON from our server to query for any products that have updated, then wish to only update those that changed, how could we accomplish this.

In the past, we would use PHP to create widgets and give them id attributes based on an ID (like “sales” + productid).  Then, when the JSON returns from our server with productIDs that changed, we could target only the widgets that are needed to be updated.  We would know their id attribute and could update them with something like:
this.element.find(“#” + “sales” + productid).html(“the changed html here”)

(yes, it was cumbersome)

In React, how can one still have this type of control to update only components that are based on some meaningful ID returned from a server or database?  Is there a way to give an ID to a component and use/target it later?

Comment: Your sales have an ID and those should be saved in your app state (plain React, Redux, or one of the many choices you have). When you receive the new data from your DB, you update only the sales that match the updated IDs. That's all there is to it

Comment: So I guess you are getting the components' data from an API, right? And are you using redux along with react?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a simple example that simulates fetching a list of products every second and will render the list. The product ID is used as a [key](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in the rendered list and will allow React to efficiently re-render the list on every update.

```js
class ProductsInfoContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { products: [] };
    this.fetchProducts = this.fetchProducts.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshTimer = setInterval(this.fetchProducts, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.refreshTimer);
  }

  fetchProducts() {
    //simulate API fetch from server - we'll just create a list with random prices
    const products = [
      {id: "123-456", name: "Widget", price: this.getPrice()},
      {id: "234-567", name: "Widget Spinner", price: this.getPrice()},
      {id: "345-678", name: "Fidget", price: this.getPrice()},
      {id: "456-789", name: "Fidget Spinner", price: this.getPrice()},
    ];
    this.setState({ products });
  }

  getPrice() {
    return (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2);
  }

  render() {
    return <ProductsInfo products={this.state.products} />;
  }
}

const ProductsInfo = ({ products }) => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {products.map(product =>
        <tr key={product.id}>
          <td>{product.id}</td>
          <td>{product.name}</td>
          <td>{product.price}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);

ReactDOM.render(<ProductsInfoContainer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

When your `products` data updates come from the server, the state change in the container will cause React to re-render your `ProductsInfo` component and will work out what has changed and update accordingly. Providing a `key` for each product makes that process a lot more efficient.

Clearly this is a trivial example, but it gives you a good idea. You are declaratively defining how the UI should look given your input data and let React worry about how to efficiently translate that into something on screen. You can get a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to a DOM node in React and update it directly, but that completely goes against the grain of what React is about and should be used sparingly IMO.

If you need to do something more complex with how you render each product, you could define another component and render that from your map function e.g.

```
{products.map(product => <Product key={product.id} info={product}/>)}
```

If you were talking about thousands (or more) of products, then perhaps you would take a different approach, or at the very least consider paging the data or the like.

Please feel free to ask any questions if anything is not clear.

Comment: Your example is great.  Providing the key into the ProductsInfo component seems to be the piece that binds it all together.  The state change of ProductsInfoContainer rippling through to ProductInfo is awesome.  And, as I was hoping, it is far less cumbersome than the way we had done this in the past without React.

Comment: Currently, the example ProductsInfo component creates and fills a table.  But if each product will have a custom div that contains info laid out in a certain manner (more like a rectangle), is this something that would get done still in the ProductsInfo component?  In our old PHP method, we would know how many products we had and would lay it out in columns with php knowing how many would fit into each column.  With React, is there a way to determine where things get arranged on the screen?

Comment: Because you're writing html in JavaScript, you can apply whatever logic you need to work out how things should be laid out. E.g. if you have 12 products and you want 3 columns, then you can easily work this out and tell React to render 3 products over 4 rows. You just need to define your components to suit your needs and put in whatever logic makes sense. Best way is to just give it a go and if you get stuck you can always check SO and post a qu if needed.