# I want to only a single component update on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to update only a single element when using setState in a function

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App(){

  const [state, setState] = useState("foo");

  return(

    <Component1/>
    <Component2/>
    <Component3/>

  );


}
```

I need some way of updating one some of those elements, but not all.

Comment: I think that this link might help you in your quest : [Update specific component instance - React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44554744/16067048)

Answer (score 0):

In functional components, you can wrap your component with `React.memo`. With this way, React will memorize the component structure and on next render, if the props still the same, React does not render again and use the memorized one. For more information, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Basically wrap with React.memo. Below code, when state1 change, Component2's render count won't increase because its props stays same. But when state2 change, both of them will render.

```
export const Component2 = React.memo(({ state2 }) => {
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  renderCount.current = renderCount.current + 1;
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: 10 }}>
      Component2(with React.memo): <b>Rendered:</b> {renderCount.current} times,{" "}
      <b>State2:</b> {state2}
    </div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(1);
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={() => setState1((state) => state + 1)}>
        Click to change state1
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => setState2((state) => state + 1)}>
        Click to change state2
      </div>
      <Component1 state1={state1} />
      <Component2 state2={state2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a sandbox for you to play. Click the buttons and see React.memo in action. https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sound-gug2x?file=/src/App.js:872-1753

Also, with Class Components, you can use PureComponents for the same purpose. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent